# jquery ui button toolbar with menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ArxAG/):

**Objective:**

1. Center jqueryui button toolbar at page bottom; toolbar is sticked at bottom.
2. Using idea from http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton; When button is clicked menu should appear opening at top side, since toolbar is sticked at bottom.

***Both of above are not working.***

**HTML:**

```
<div id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all sticky">
    <button id="gear">gear</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="disk">disk</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Usage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quota</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="trash">trash</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Folders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    //
    //gear Button
    //
    $("#gear").button({
        label: "gear",
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-gear"
        }
    }).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var menu = $(this).next().show().position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: this
        });


    }).next().hide().menu();
    //
    //disk Button
    //
    $("#disk").button({
        label: "disk",
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-disk"
        }
    }).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }).next().hide().menu();
    //
    //trash Button
    //
    $("#trash").button({
        label: "trash",
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-trash"
        }
    }).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }).next().hide().menu();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

To center your toolbar on the bottom, you should give width. After you put on the toolbar `position: absolute`.

Play with `left` and `margin-left` to center `#toolbar`

http://jsfiddle.net/ArxAG/12/

```
body{
    width:100%;
}

#toolbar {
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.seems to be working.But how can i fix Menu opening ?